# Change associated list in sharepoint designer approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

Is it possible to change associated list in SharePoint designer approval workflow?
I want to make the entry in other list instead of default list. Let me know if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create custom form for workflow associated list. You need to create new form in .NET and then assign to associated form of sharepoint workflow

Go through [Link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thirusrinivasan1/archive/2013/09/25/sharepoint-2013-workflow-integrating-a-custom-association-form.aspx) [Link2](http://splearningcurve.blogspot.in/2013/07/sharepoint-custom-workflow-part-3.html).